# How to get hi-hats in FL studio rewire in cubase?

Tags: cubase

I want to get hihats from fruity loops in cubase with rewire. I can get the kick and other sounds but there is no hihat available. How can I control it?

Comment: As Don stated, another (in my opinion, the best) option is to use FL Studio as a VST.

Comment: Full disclosure: I ripped the FL Studio .wav drum samples off the free demo and have been using them for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a limitation on the number of channels availible in rewire as well (either on the host side or the client side).

If the high-hats are sample based, you may be able to pull them into a sampler in Cubase. The same is true for VSTs. FL Studio does have a couple of FL only plug-ins though.

To move the song data, you might have to create a midi track in FL, copy the patterns to that track, and export the song (while in pattern mode) to MIDI... then import the MIDI track in Cubase.

Another option is to use FL Studio directly as a VST itself inside of Cubase.